# How to update existing data in Apache Druid

Tags: datasource, druid

The problem was to add a new field to existing datasource and fill it with some default value.
I have tried so via [this aticle](https://support.imply.io/hc/en-us/articles/360004050913-How-to-create-a-new-dimension-and-fill-the-column-with-default-value-during-ingestion)

But the actual result is that new column was added, but it filled with a null value.
Where I was wrong and can I fix it in the same way?

Answer (score 2):

It would be hard to tell without looking at how you have added the new column in your ingestions spec.

I will suggest using druid unified console data loader UI > and parse your input data > define the additional column under `transform` section. The advantage of data loader UI is that you can preview the transformed result immediately and once the workflow is completed you will get an ingestions spec and can submit it from there itself.

Eg-
[Transformation example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSeKf.png)

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation here: https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/design/segments.html#different-schemas-among-segments

Maybe the result is related to the fact that existing segments don't have the new field and therefore show null.